# "500 Internal Server Error" occur when passing the HTTP request using EA Azure Billing API

Tags: c#, azure, azure-web-app-service

This code applicable for azure EA customers. Can't able to guess it is a browser setting issue or account relates issues. But i checked the code with my EA account

```
static void Main(string[] args)
{
string token ="xxxx"
string url = "https://ea.azure.com/rest/{PortalNumber}/usage-report?month=2/5/2016&type=summary";
string a = CallRestAPI(url,token);
}        
static string CallRestAPI(string url, string token)
{
WebRequest request = WebRequest.Create(url);
request.Headers.Add("authorization", "bearer " + token);             
request.Headers.Add("api-version", "1.0");
HttpWebResponse response = (HttpWebResponse)request.GetResponse();
StreamReader reader = new StreamReader (response.GetResponseStream());
return  reader.ReadToEnd(); 
}
```

Comment: "500 Internal Server Error" means an error occurred on the server. We cannot know what error they received unless that's included in the response, and you'll need to post it in your question. But 5xx errors usually indicate a problem on the server, not in your own client code.